# How to draw jagged pixellated line in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, pixel, antialiasing

I am able to draw a line using OpenGL, which produces the following result:

[image: smooth line]

However, this line looks smooth and out-of-place compared to the pixellated style of my game. I would prefer a result that looks more like this:

[image: rough line]

Can someone please give me some tips on how I can get OpenGL to draw a pixellated line like this?

Here is my renderLine() method (using immediate mode, I'm afraid):

```
public static void renderLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2,
        float thickness, float[] colour) {

    // Store model matrix to prevent contamination
    glPushMatrix();

    // Set colour and thickness
    glColor4f(colour[0], colour[1], colour[2], colour[3]);
    glLineWidth(thickness);

    // Draw line
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
        glVertex2f(x1, y1);
        glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    }
    glEnd();

    // Restore previous state
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glLineWidth(1.0f);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really nothing built-in in OpenGL to draw such lines.

You could draw a tight quad containing the pixels in the line and use a fragment shader that evaluates which pixels are to be left in and which are to left out.

However, considering that you want the look of all your game to be pixellated, the best solution is to render to a smaller texture and then blit it to the screen with x4 (or whatever factor) nearest neighbor interpolation. Then drawing such line reduces to just a regular `GL_LINE` without `GL_LINE_SMOOTH`ing.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that entities in my game are not necessarily aligned to the rendered pixels of the game world. They can be positioned "between" pixels, which allows for much smoother movement than if they were restricted to the pixel grid. If I were to render the whole game in a pixel-perfect fashion onto a smaller texture, I would lose this extra precision. However, I may be able to use this approach for just the line rendering - thanks!

Comment: @Dan: You can still use the approach with the shader.